# Confusion in Deriving Formula for Energy in Terms of Normal Modes

Tags: energy, normal-modes

If we have an equation of motion of the form
$$ \mathbf{\ddot{y}} = -A\cdot\mathbf{y}$$ for a real symmetric matrix $A$, we can dot product both sides of the equation by $\mathbf{\dot{y}}$ to obtain an exact differential:
$$\mathbf{\dot{y}}\cdot \mathbf{\ddot{y}} = -\mathbf{\dot{y}}\cdot A\cdot\mathbf{y}$$
\begin{equation}\therefore \frac{d}{dt}  \left(\frac{\mathbf{\dot{y}^2}}{2}+\frac{\mathbf{y} \cdot A \cdot \mathbf{y}}{2} \right) =0 \end{equation}
which uses the symmetric property of $A$ ($\mathbf{\dot{y}}\cdot A\cdot\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{y}\cdot A\cdot\mathbf{\dot{y}}$).
We have a conserved quantity, which we can call the energy of the system, made from terms representing kinetic and potential energy respectively. To express this energy in terms of the normal modes, $\xi_i$s of the system, we substitute $\mathbf{y} = R \cdot \mathbf{\xi}$ where $R$ is a matrix with normalised eigenvectors of $A$ as columns. This gives:

$$\mathscr{E} = \frac{\mathbf{\dot{\xi}}\cdot R^T \cdot R \cdot \mathbf{\dot{\xi}}}{2}+\frac{\mathbf{\xi}\cdot R^T \cdot A \cdot R \cdot \mathbf{\xi}}{2} = \frac{\lvert{\mathbf{\dot{\xi}}}\lvert}{2}+\frac{\mathbf{\xi}\cdot L\cdot \mathbf{\xi}}{2}$$
where $L = R^T \cdot A \cdot R $ is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of A and $\mathscr{E}$ is the energy - hence decoupling the system. This substitution is immediately carried out in the text I am taking this from, but it is not immediately obvious to me, how, for example, you can substitute in $\mathbf{y} = R \cdot \mathbf{\xi}$, hence $\mathbf{\dot{y}^2} = \left(R \cdot \mathbf{\dot{\xi}}\right)^2$, into the original equation, and end up with $\mathbf{\dot{\xi}}\cdot R^T \cdot R \cdot \mathbf{\dot{\xi}}$, which implies $R \cdot \mathbf{\dot{\xi}= \dot{\xi}}\cdot R^T $.  If anyone can see why this works in particular, as well as the 2nd fraction in the equation, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from the term like $\vec{y}\cdot\vec{y}$ or  $\dot{\vec{y}}\cdot\dot{\vec{y}}$, because any orthogonal matrix (transform) will preserve the norm of a vector.

Since the orthogonal matrix is made of the eigen vectors of matrix **A**, the imposing transformation can only be seen clearly from the potential term:

$$
    V(\vec{y}) = \frac{1}{2} \vec{y}^T \bf{A}\vec{y} \tag{1}
$$
where  $\vec{y}^T$ is a row vector, the transport of $\vec{y}$.

Followed the consideration in diagonlize the matrix **A**:
$$
   \bf{D} = \bf{R}^T \bf{A} \bf{R} \tag{2}
$$
This orthogonal transformation has **A** turned into a diagonal matrix **D** ( your  **L**).

Therefore, in Eq.(1) place a $\bf{R}^T$ in front of **A**, and **R** after **A**
, then you need to add the counter part to maintain the equation $\bf{R}^T \bf{R} = \bf{I} = \bf{R} \bf{R}^T$:

$$
    V(\vec{y}) = \frac{1}{2} \vec{y}^T \bf{R} \bf{R}^T\bf{A}\bf{R} \bf{R}^T\vec{y}= \frac{1}{2}( \vec{y}^T \bf{R} ) (\bf{R}^T\bf{A}\bf{R}) (\bf{R}^T\vec{y})\tag{3}
$$
After diagonalization equation (3) becomes:
$$
    V(\vec{\xi}) = \frac{1}{2} \vec{\xi}^T \bf{D} \vec{\xi}\tag{4}
$$

Compare Eq. (3) and Eq.(4), we have:
$$
\vec{\xi} = \bf{R}^T \vec{y}, \text{ or } \vec{y} = \bf{R} \vec{\xi};\\
\vec{\xi}^T =  \vec{y}^T \bf{R}, \text{ or } \vec{y}^T = \vec{\xi}^T \bf{R}^T
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how do I get from there to $\mathscr{E} = \frac{\mathbf{\dot{\xi}}\cdot R^T \cdot R \cdot \mathbf{\dot{\xi}}}{2}+\frac{\mathbf{\xi}\cdot R^T \cdot A \cdot R \cdot \mathbf{\xi}}{2} = \frac{\lvert{\mathbf{\dot{\xi}}}\lvert}{2}+\frac{\mathbf{\xi}\cdot L\cdot \mathbf{\xi}}{2}$?

Comment: If you use notation of matrix multiplication, $ | \vec{\xi} |^2 = \vec{\xi} \cdot \vec{\xi} = \vec{\xi}^T \vec{\xi} $ . Or, I might miss your meaning.

Comment: Ah, no that makes perfect sense, thank you very much!